# How to get special characters in URL variables to output correctly using PHP and GET

Tags: php, url, get, special-characters

I've an issue I've just encountered (once the web app is already up and running for a week!) and I can't seem to solve it, and I'm sort of rushing through it in order to fix it before it continues malfunctioning.

I've coded a neat little Christmas card for a business and the user inputs his/her name and the name of someone else and then sends it, so the card says *TO: JOHN, FROM: PAUL*, basically.

This info is sent via URL vars and then, of course, I use `GET` to retrieve it and output the message.

Of course, it's a card one can use from anyone and to anyone... but I tested it only in English (my bad). So when the first Martín or Sören comes around and uses the card, they get **From: Martã­n**, **From: Sã¶ren**...

Obviously, that doesn't work.

So I'm guessing I need to find a way either to transform the special character from the input field into the URL or from the URL to the output message. (While we're on the subject: which would you recommend?)

However, I can't get it to work. I've tried finding which character codes work when sent through the URL.

I've noticed URLs usually substitute certain characters and especially white spaces with a % and something else (a coding method whose name I don't know; can anyone enlighten me on that, please?). But when I try `%C3%AD`, which, according to a website I found, is the code for **í**, as in my example **Martín**, I continue to get the ã­, as these codes in the URL are automatically changed to their special character.

I've also tried `&iacute;`, `&#237;` but to no avail!

Comment: Are you using UTF-8? Have you tried using php's htmlentities() function to convert a string to see what gets output correctly? Because then you can use html_entity_decode()

Comment: Can you display your form markup? try accept-charset="UTF-8"

Comment: Use `rawurlencode($str)` Take a look [here][1]. Looks like my answer was too short...


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419075/converting-utf8-text-for-use-in-a-url#2419208

Answer (score 2):

You can try using rawurlencode, check out the examples there. Hope this helps.

http://www.php.net/rawurlencode

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurldecode.php